# How to select max timestamp from each currency pair SQL?

Tags: sql

Say I have a table

```
TIMESTAMP    curr1    curr2    rate
2017-01-01   USD      GBP      0.81
2017-01-01   EUR      GBP      0.98
2017-01-03   USD      GBP      0.83
```

and I want to get the currency pair rate with the **latest TIMESTAMP for each currency pair**, so this is the output:

```
TIMESTAMP    curr1    curr2    rate
2017-01-03   USD      GBP      0.83
2017-01-01   EUR      GBP      0.98
```

I am unsure how to do this using `distinct` and `group by` functions. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm unsure how to do this with `distinct` and `group by` as well.  Perhaps someone else can address that.

I would use a correlated subquery in most databases:

```
select t.*
from atable t
where t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                     from atable t2
                     where t2.curr1 = t.curr1 and t2.curr2 = t.curr2
                    );
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by a group by and a join:

```
SELECT x.TIMESTAMP, x.curr1, x.curr2 
FROM your_table x 
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) max_timestamp, curr1, curr2 FROM your_table 
     GROUP BY curr1, curr2
) y
ON x.TIMESTAMP= y.max_timestamp
AND x.curr1 = y.curr1
AND x.curr2 = y.curr2;
```