# Select highest value linked to title - sql

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to select the highest pair from a table that has been created by joining (combining) two tables. I guess I should use a nested query but I'm not sure how.
I also came around a similar question that seems a bit less complex, but I am struggling to implement it into my problem.

Similar question: [How to select max timestamp from each currency pair SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728389/how-to-select-max-timestamp-from-each-currency-pair-sql)

My tables:

Book:

| title | publisher | price | sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| book1 | A | 5 | 300 |
| book2 | B | 15 | 150 |
| book3 | A | 8 | 350 |

Publisher:

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| A | ABook |
| B | BBook |
| C | CBook |

My query:

```
SELECT b.titel, p.name, max(b.price*b.sold) as 'Revenue"
FROM publisher p, book b
WHERE p.code = b.publisher
```

Gives:

| title | publisher | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| book1 | ABook | 1500 |
| book2 | BBook | 2250 |
| book3 | ABook | 2800 |

Desired output:

| title | publisher |
| --- | --- |
| book2 | BBook |
| book3 | ABook |

How to alter my query to get the highest revenue per book title and the corresponding publisher?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT b.titel, p.name
FROM publisher p, book b
WHERE p.code = b.publisher
order by b.price*b.sold desc
```

OR

```
select abc.titel,abc.name FROM (
select  b.titel, p.name, max( b.price*b.sold) as balance
FROM publisher p, book b
WHERE p.code = b.publisher
group by  b.titel, p.name ) abc order by abc.balance desc
```

Comment: But I'm only interested in the highest revenue per publisher and the corresponding book title. I edited my question because I thought I was unclear as well.

Comment: please try or section

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` window function to select the appropriate row for each group.

Your desired results don't align with your description (do you want a revenue column or not?), however this produces your desired output. Note the use of modern (for 30 years) ansi join syntax:

```
with sold as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by publisher order by (price * sold) desc) rn
    from book b join publisher p on p.code=b.publisher
)
select title, name Publusher
from sold
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a nested query and max function

```
select b.title, p.name
    from book b join publisher p on p.code = b.publisher
    where b.sold*b.price = (select max(sold*price)
                     from book t2
                     where t2.publisher = b.publisher
                    )
```